# Почему большие простые числа так долго генерируются

Tags: java

Мне нужно сгенерировать несколько больших чисел с определенным условием, но проблема в том, что они не генерируются вовсе, в том же c# аналогичный код генерирует достаточно быстро все нужные мне числа. Вот как выглядит условие генерирования чисел:

Перейдем к описанию системы. Пусть есть два абонента A и B, соединенные линией связи. A хочет передать сообщение m абоненту B так, чтобы никто не узнал его содержание. A выбирает случайное большое простое число p и открыто передает его B. Затем A выбирает два числа cA и dA , такие, что

```
cAdA mod (p − 1) = 1.
```

Эти числа A держит в секрете и передавать не будет. B тоже выбирает два числа cB и dB , такие, что

```
cBdB mod (p − 1) = 1
```

Вот как я реализовал:

```
BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(64, random);

        BigInteger Ca = null;
        BigInteger Da = null;
        BigInteger Cb = null;
        BigInteger Db = null;

        System.out.println(p);

        do {
            Ca = new BigInteger(64, random);
            Da = new BigInteger(64, random);
        } while((!((Ca.multiply(Da)).mod(p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))).equals(BigInteger.ONE))
                || Ca.compareTo(p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) > 0
                || Da.compareTo(p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) > 0);


        do {
            Cb = new BigInteger(64, random);
            Db = new BigInteger(64, random);
        } while((!((Cb.multiply(Db)).mod(p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))).equals(BigInteger.ONE))
                || Cb.compareTo(p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) > 0
                || Db.compareTo(p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) > 0)
```

В чем причина такого долго генерирования в BigInt? Как можно решить эту задачу иначе?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос оригинальный код на C#.

Comment: @NowhereMan, они и не простые, просто случайные.

Answer (score 1):

Описание данной задачи похоже на [трёхэтапный протокол Шамира](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0#) или же [шифр Шамира](https://studfile.net/preview/7116437/page:15/)

Пары чисел `cA, dA` и `cB, dB` должны не подбираться рандомно, а вычисляться, исходя из условия `c * d % (p - 1) = 1`.  Первым числом, соответствующим данной формуле будет само число `p`:

```
p % (p - 1) = ((p - 1) + 1) % (p - 1) = 0 + 1 = 1
```

Все остальные числа будут удовлетворять отношению:

```
Q = c * d = p + (p - 1) * N
```

Соответственно для подбора указанных пар чисел, достаточно выбрать *случайным* образом для каждой стороны число N и разложить получившееся число `Q` на два множителя, каждый из которых должен отличаться от 1, то есть, придется дополнительно отфильтровать случаи, когда число `Q` может быть простым, например, при `p = 19`, последовательность доступных произведений будет: **19**, **37**, 55, **73**, 91, **109**, **127**, 145, **163**... (выделены простые числа)